# Get data array from PHP to JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, json

I want to get data array from php to Javascript. (Actually I am doing plotting using javascript library and the data is in the database: I get the data using php script and want to use that data for plotting). I have tried to use a JSON for this. My code looks follows but it is not working. Please give me a help on this

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

<?php

 $php_arr=array('abc','def'); // I want to transport this array to javascript

  echo "display_diagram(" . json_encode($php_arr) . ")";
?>

    function display_diagram(data) {


       obj = JSON.parse(data); // this is not working for me
```

Comment: what means *not working*?

Comment: You don't have to parse it at all. The parameter "data" will be the actual array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try use `data` variable in `display_diagram` function without `JSON.parse`.
You now give `data` attribute in json format and this not require additional json parsing.

Check this:

```
<script>
<?php

 $php_arr=array('abc','def'); // I want to transport this array to javascript

  echo "display_diagram(" . json_encode($php_arr) . ")";
?>

function display_diagram(data){

    obj = data;
    alert(obj);
}
</script>
```